# Why is it that in a do while statement if I want to check for case sensitivity I have to use "and" instead of "or"?

Tags: c++, logic

`

```
    do
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do: ";
        getline(cin, input);
        

    } while (input != "quit" and input != "Quit" and input != "QUIT");



    cout << "Great Thanks!" << endl << endl;
```

`
I just can't get my head around why I have to use and instead of or in the while part. Shouldn't it be that if the input is not quit OR the input is not Quit then it would proceed to the next thing?

I tried understanding the logic of this, I cant understand it. Maybe im just really stupid.

Comment: Suppose `input` is `"QUIT"` ... You would have `while (true or true or false)` if you ignore short circuiting, which evaluates to `true`, so the loop keeps going instead of quitting.

Comment: Ohh I see so two of them would be true. Thanks for explaining

Comment: The way you're thinking about it is backward with how the operators work.   You are testing three conditions  `input != "quit"`, `input != "Quit"`, and `input != "QUIT"` which all have to be true for the loop to continue.    Changing the `and` to `or` means the loop will continue if ANY of those three conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have balls and hoops of different colors, and you want to check that what you have is not a ball. You might try to say this:

> It if is not a red or green or blue ball, it is a hoop.

This sounds fine on the surface, but this would be a different expression, such as `ball in [RED_BALL, BLUE_BALL, GREEN_BALL]`, or

```
while (!(input == "quit" or input == "Quit" or input == "QUIT"))
```

This ↑ is much easier to read, I think! Less negation.

What `input != "quit" and input != "Quit" and input != "QUIT"` does is,

> If it is not a red ball, or if it is not a green ball, or if is not blue ball, it is a hoop.

Or in other words

> If is not a red ball, it is a hoop; if is not a green ball, it is also a hoop; if is not a blue ball, it is also a hoop.

As a blue ball is not a red ball, it satisfies the condition. In fact, as the ball can't be of three colors at the same time, this will *always* say that it is a hoop.

On the other hand, if you use “and”,

> If it's not a blue ball, and not a red ball, and not a green ball, it must be a hoop

Or in other words

> If it's not a blue ball, and at the same time not a red ball, and at the same time not a green ball, it must be a hoop

Then you have no issues.